# Route Exception with a post Method

Tags: laravel

I have a MethodNotAllowedHttpException with a button for a post method , it's really strange because i made the same process with a lot of others things in the project but with this route don't want to work . Where i made a mistake ?

thanks a lot in advance friends :)

Here my route :

```
Route::post('licencies_to_update/{id}', 'LicencieController@Renouveller')->name('licencie.renouveller');
```

Here my button in my blade view :

```
{!! link_to_route('licencie.renouveller', 'Effectuer le Renouvellement' , [$licencie->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

Here the begin of my controller :

```
 public function Renouveller(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $licencie = Licencies::findOrFail($id);

        dd($licencie);
```

....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

`Route::get('licencies_to_update/{id}', 'LicencieController@Renouveller')
->name('licencie.renouveller');`

instead of `POST` method. Because in the link of your button you are not requesting the url with a `POST` method but `GET` method. Besides, you are not doing anything related to `POST` variable. You are passing a simple variable `id` in your route param. So, no need to use `POST` param here.

Comment: In Fact with a GET method it's working ! thanks so much

Comment: You are welcome and if is solves your problem don't forget to approve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The link you are creating is an anchor to the route you provided, but the link is a GET request, while you specify in your routes file that you want POST requests on that url.

Either create a form or change the method that route accepts (or let it also accept GET requests)

Edit:
Change your route to

```
Route::get('licencies_to_update/{id}', 'LicencieController@Renouveller')->name('licencie.renouveller');
```

to have the expected result the fastest!

Comment: It's working with a GET Method now ! thanks so much once again Douwe de Haan !!!!!!!

Comment: And again no problem! ;)